# How do I update the default useSate value from a html input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, default-value

This Is a simple question. I have a React useState hook,

`const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);`

how would I be able to update the useState default of 0 to any number I enter, from some kind of a text box or Input in HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a change event in the input then add the function to handle the input change. like this example.

```
export default function App() {
const [seconds, setSecond]= useState(0);

const handleSeondChange = (event)=>{
  setSecond(event.currentTarget.value);
}
return (
  <div className="App">
    <input name ="seconds" value={seconds} onChange={handleSecondChange}/>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within an input tag include an `onChange` handler. For example, `<input onChange={(event) => setSeconds(event.target.value)} value={seconds}/>`. You're dealing with a controlled input here, so make sure you include the value tag within the input like I included above.